# Suitable Autoencoder for Activity Recognition dataset Feature Extraction

Tags: neural-network, classification, feature-extraction, autoencoder, rbm

I have text data representing sensor outputs.

**Dataset**:

```
1458996986002;    11.43,-15.86,11.20,508.26;        -1.59,-0.22,6.17,40.68;        126.0,-150.9,-105.0,49671.81;        Walk
1459002923002;    16.69,-12.68,13.96,634.65;        -2.55,2.13,4.87,34.87;         126.0,-150.9,-105.0,49671.81;        Walk


timestamp;    acc_x,acc_y,acc_z;    gyro_x,gyro_y,gyro_z;    magn_x,magn_y,magn_z;    ActivityName
```

**My Goal**: I would like to extract features from the text lines before feeding it into a Recurrent Neural Network (GRU/LSTM). So, my goal is **automatic feature extraction**. Those extracted features (encoder network) will be used before the neural network for an activity recognition task (classification).

**My Question**:  Which Autoencoder (denoising, variational, sparse) is suitable for such dataset? Or should I use RBM instead? After choosing a feature extraction method, how do I compare the output with input, since the input is not 0s and 1s?

**What I have read**: I read that RBM is generative model, which, even if you give some similar input, it can generate similar correct output. And training autoencoder is [said(1)](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/20ue0z/what_are_the_practical_difference_between_an_rbm/cg74tpy/?st=jex5e27b&sh=5cb31722) [to be easier(2)](http://qr.ae/TU1pGg) than RBM. On the other hand, variational autoencoder can do something similar ([generative](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/328181/193154)). **First question would be is having *generative* ability has any advantage for above problem, because at the end of pretraining i would just use encoder part and throw decoder layers**? If no, denoising autoencoder seems right approach I'm my opinion.

Last thing: I know to force network to learn important features from data (instead of memorizing), you can choose following methods: 1) [use sandwich like layers](https://towardsdatascience.com/applied-deep-learning-part-3-autoencoders-1c083af4d798), 2) add noise to input 3) [regularize autoencoder](https://towardsdatascience.com/applied-deep-learning-part-3-autoencoders-1c083af4d798)=make only some nodes active at the same time

Comment: Also i will be providing about 100 readings at once (based on window size like 2seconds) to autoencoder

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to do activity recognition based on time windows using deep learning models with autoencoders I would strongly suggest to have a look at the following articles:

[This](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323019783_An_Effective_Deep_Autoencoder_Approach_for_Online_Smartphone-Based_Human_Activity_Recognition) gives an overview of a custom CNN/RNN model which might give an initial idea of how to proceed for the specific task of AR.

and

[This](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8422895) gives a general idea of how to reconstruct sensor data with semantic meanings before feeding the constructed data features to another model.